Simulating Sports Results - Which probability rule do I need?
Apologies if this has been answered already, I have been searching for a while but have not yet found my answer.  I assume this is a straightforward problem for knowledgeable people, but it has been a long time since I studied probabilities and when I did it was basic!
I am messing around with simulated sports leagues for a project I am working on.  I'm confused with calculating probabilities for each possible game outcome (Team 1 wins, Team 2 wins or tie) for a given game, based on each team's statistical history.
Let's say: over a given sample of games:
Team 1 wins 75%, loses 24% and ties 1% of their games and
Team 2 wins 65%, loses 34% and ties 1% of their games.
As with a real game, there has to be exactly one outcome when Team 1 and Team 2 play each other.  What probability rule do I need to use to work out the respective probabilities of either team winning and of the tie, based purely on the teams' performances in this sample of games?
I hope I have explained this clearly!  Thanks in advance for your help, guys!

You understand that predicting the outcome of sports is hard? There are a lot of variables.  You need a model and even with one you'll probably be wrong

I'm not attempting to predict real games.  I'm trying to calculate the probabilities as described above purely from the figures given.  Thanks.

Alas,  you can't.

@lulu That is not exactly true.  The (unrealistic) computation in my answer is not a bad estimate of what the actual computation would be, assuming a more detailed analysis by professional sports bettors.  It is understood that the computation will sometimes underestimate the better team's chances, because a $~75%~$ team is sometimes much better than a $~65%~$ team.  Further, the entire approach ignores the issue of individual matchups.  Still, with these qualifications, the math isn't that wildly far off.

Thanks for reading, @lulu.

@user2661923 Given only the win rates, it's possible that either Team 1 or Team 2 could have up to a 100% probability of winning against the other. The math could be very far off if there are particular matchups that swing one way or another. Winning 65% of games doesn't mean you have a 65% chance of winning each game, it might mean you have a 100% chance of winning 65% of your games and 0% for the rest.

@NuclearHoagie True, and discussed in my answer, but not relevant to the posted question.  Excerpting: "What probability rule do I need to use to work out the respective probabilities of either team winning and of the tie, based purely on the teams' performances in this sample of games?"


What probability rule do I need to use to work out the respective probabilities of either team winning and of the tie, based purely on the teams' performances in this sample of games?

As shown below, the specific math problem posed can be solved.  However, the computed answer will only apply to a fairy tale world, that has no basis in reality.  In reality, how upper echelon teams do against each other can not be reliably inferred based on their respective performances against the remainder of the league.
There are a variety of reasons for this.  However, the entire subject is beyond the bounds of a math forum.

Anyway, for the specific math problem posed:

Let's say: over a given sample of games:
Team 1 wins 75%, loses 24% and ties 1% of their games and
Team 2 wins 65%, loses 34% and ties 1% of their games.

Besides the unrealistic aspects mentioned in the previous section, you also have to assume that the Team 1 outcomes are (somehow) independent of the Team 2 outcomes.  While moderately inaccurate, this assumption is not that unreasonable, because the Team 1 outcomes are against the league as a whole, so very few of the Team 1 outcomes are based on Team 1 vs Team 2.
Similarly, very few of the Team 2 outcomes are based on Team 1 vs Team 2.
One of the following three events must occur:

Team 1 wins: 
The probability of this happening is 
$0.75 \times 0.34 = 0.255.$

Team 2 wins: 
The probability of this happening is 
$0.24 \times 0.65 = 0.156.$

The game is a tie: 
This is a special statistic.  The computation of $~(0.01) \times (0.01)~$ is so wildly inaccurate that it must be discarded.
A tie is a special statistic that I will discuss below. 
Let $~T~$ denote the probability of a tie.


So, you are guaranteed that one of the three events above occurred.  So, in effect, you are working in a sample space of
$$(0.255) + (0.156) + T.$$
Before mounting the final attack on the problem, some reasonable estimate of $~T~$ must be given.  Since each team has $~1\%~$ of their games ending in a tie, I will arbitrarily estimate that
$$T = [ ~(0.255) + (0.156) ~] \times \frac{1}{99}.$$
Then, the probability of :

A winning is $~\displaystyle \frac{0.255}{[ ~0.255 + 0.156 ~] \times (100/99)}.$

B winning is $~\displaystyle \frac{0.156}{[ ~0.255 + 0.156 ~] \times (100/99)}.$

Tie game is $~(1/100).$



$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
In this section, I am going to try to return to earth (somewhat) by repairing the posted question itself, so that the principles of conditional probability may be reasonably applied.
Suppose that you have two weather forecasters, A and B, that each forecast either rain or no rain.
Further suppose that A is right $~75\%~$ of the time and B is right $~65\%~$ of the time.
Further suppose that the evidence that A uses to predict the weather is somehow independent of the evidence that B uses to predict the weather.  From this, you can infer that A's prediction is independent of B's prediction.
Now suppose that on a given day, they disagree on whether it will rain.  Then, the probability that
A is right is
$$\frac{0.75 \times 0.35}{(0.75 \times 0.35) + (0.65 \times 0.25)}.$$

Perfect, exactly what I was looking to understand!  Thanks very much for your helpful answer.

Uh, I'm still curious actually...
Could you elaborate on the probability formulae given?  Do they have a name or use a specific rule that I can look up?  In the win ones, where does the (100/99) come from?

@MatthewFarr No specific rule.  The formula is jury-rigged by me so that the probability of a tie will be $~1/100.~$  This implies that the ratio between $~T~$ and $~(1 - T)~$ must be $~1::99.$

Ok, thanks again!
